# How to prevent direct access particular page in magento?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, magento-1.9

I am developing a Magento e-commerce website and I want to restrict particular page from direct access in URL.

www.mydomain.com/index.php/test.html

But it must be accessible through the homepage or any domain page when clicked on that page link.

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct path? Usually a PHP file is not a directory that can hold a HTML file.

Comment: ya, that is correct link actually I am fetching all the data dynamically.test.html is a section of my e-commerce website.you can also tell me how to restrict PHP file from accessing through a direct link.

Comment: Usually by setting some sort of cookie, if the cookie is not set, redirect them elsewhere

Comment: Edited for spelling corrections